# Azure Storage Emulator store data on specific path

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

At my current PC setup I have an SSD and a normal hard drive installed.
The SSD only has a capacity of 120GB and since I'm developing a large application which stores allot of files in azure blob storage I whish to specify to which hard drive the microsoft azure storage emulator has to store my files.

I am using the latest storage emulator (3.0).

Thx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Storage emulator keeps this setting in a file called **`WAStorageEmulator.5.2.config`** which can be found in **`C:\Users\{Your Current User Name}\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator`** folder. Open up this file and change the settings for **`PageBlobRoot`** and **`BlockBlobRoot`** elements in that configuration file. For example, in the XML below, I changed the settings so that the files are written in `D:\` for block blobs instead of `C:\`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StorageEmulator xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SQLInstance>.\SQLExpress</SQLInstance>
  <PageBlobRoot>C:\Users\Gaurav.Mantri\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\PageBlobRoot</PageBlobRoot>
  <BlockBlobRoot>D:\Users\Gaurav.Mantri\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\BlockBlobRoot</BlockBlobRoot>
  <LogPath>C:\Users\Gaurav.Mantri\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\Logs</LogPath>
  <LoggingEnabled>false</LoggingEnabled>
</StorageEmulator>
```

You may need to restart the storage emulator for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Now it's named `AzureStorageEmulator` so the path is `%userprofile%\Local\AzureStorageEmulator`

Comment: FYI the newest path is `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator`