# BlockBlobRoot folder in Azure Storage locally

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I found a folder named BlockBlobRoot in my local folder: `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\WAStorageEmulator\` , its size increased quickly.

My question is:

1. What and where data come from in this folder?
2. Can I keep its size not increase so much or maintain in a certain size?
3. Can this folder be moved to somewhere other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What and where data come from in this folder?

This is where files uploaded in storage emulator are stored. So when you're uploading the files in storage emulator, a file is created in this folder and a reference of this file goes into the database for storage emulator.

> Can I keep its size not increase so much or maintain in a certain
>   size?

I don't think so. One way is to periodically delete files from blob storage. That should automatically delete the files from here.

> Can this folder be moved to somewhere other place?

Yes, it can be moved. Please see this thread for more details: [Azure Storage Emulator store data on specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671111/azure-storage-emulator-store-data-on-specific-path)

Comment: I had a look at my `WAStorageEmulatorDB30/dbo.Blob`, found it generated a lot of containers, such as `wad-control-container`, `wad-iis-failedreqlogfiles` .etc, their `DirectoryPath` indicate they are located at the `BlockBlobRoot` folder, what's the rule they generated? I found that as I ran my CloudService, a lot of record has been added to this table? Are they from Diagnostics or somewhere I can configure?

Comment: You're correct. `wad-*` containers are from diagnostics. If I'm not mistaken, if your project has enabled diagnostics these containers **will** be created. You could simply clean up diagnostics data periodically to keep the size of this folder smaller.

Comment: Do you mean I should clean the folder manually or in the code?

Comment: Never clean up this folder manually as it is referenced in the database containing storage emulator data. But you don't have to write code also to do that. Use any available storage explorer which allows you to connect with storage emulator. Simple solution would be to delete the blob container. If you want more elegant solution, do take a look at Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata. It has diagnostics cleanup functionality which deletes the data contained in these container without deleting the container itself.